# I need to cut columns 5 & 6 from a few hundred files

Tags: file, unix, awk, sed, cut

I have multiple CSV files. I need to remove columns 5 and 6 from them. Example `file.csv`:

```
column1,column2,column3,mm/dd/yyyy,column5,column6,column7,...,column52
```

I have searched and nothing seems to be as simple as it should. I was hoping for a `sed` solution so it will update each file in place. I will not rename the files they will remain the same except for the cut files will now be gone.

Comment: Are any fields quoted? Like this: `column3, "column4, comma in field", column5`. (That is just 3 fields but any trivial regex solution will break into 4 and break the quoted fields.) Do the fields have the spaces between columns after the comma as you show? CSV is surprisingly complicated...

Comment: There are no spaces in between the commas. There are no quotations but there are spaces in some of the fields. as well as slashes in the date fields and colons in the timestamps.

Comment: Please fix your example then. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `cut` in a loop, assuming all your files have at least 7 columns:

```
for file in *.csv; do
  cut -f1-4,7- -d, "$file" > "$file".reduced
  # move reduced file to original once tested
  # mv "$file".reduced "$file"
done
```

- `-f1-4,7-` => get fields 1-4, and then 7 onwards (basically, remove 5 & 6)

Comment: I have quickly tested the cut & move. It seems to work. I will further test this before accepting your answer. Thank You.

Comment: In order to rename the multiple files I plan to use:
 `for i in *.csv.reduced 
 do 
 j=`echo $i | sed "s/.reduced//"` 
 mv $i $j 
 done `

Answer (score 1):

With GNU sed:

```
 sed 's/,[^,]*//4;s/,[^,]*//4' file
```

Add the `-i` flag to edit the file in place:

```
sed -i 's/,[^,]*//4;s/,[^,]*//4' file
```

or shorter:

```
sed 's/\([^,]*,\)\{2\}//3' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -p -i -e '{if(/(.*),(.*),(.*),(.*),.*,.*,(.*)/) {print "$1,$2,$3,$4,$5\n"}}' file.csv
```

This will directly update the file after removing the 5th and 6th columns.